# how to create multiple columns using values in one column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, etl

The data is currently structured like:

| data |
| --- |
| name1 |
| addr1 |
| url1 |
| vol1 |
| name2 |
| addr2 |
| url2 |
| vol2 |
| name3 |
| addr3 |
| url3 |
| vol3 |

expected structure:

| Name | Addr | url | Vol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | addr1 | url1 | vol1 |
| name2 | addr2 | url2 | vol2 |
| name3 | addr3 | url3 | vol3 |

I need to extract the data from a column and based on a criteria i.e. if the record is name, id, url or volume, create a column for each

Comment: Are the rows always in order: name, addr, urlm col?

Comment: No, there are some instances where the order changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that the values you provided are not the real values: ie the values are meaningful and not literally numbered like that. Data usually just isn't that nicely stated.

It also assumes that you always have a recurrent series of name, addresses, etc that recurs every four rows without exception with a well-behaving `df.index` that is merely a numeric count for every row.

Make indicies specifying which row and which column each element will end up in.

```
>>> df['columns'] = df.index % 4
>>> df['rows'] = df.index // 4
>>> df[['rows', 'columns', 'data']]
    rows  columns   data
0      0        0  name1
1      0        1  addr1
2      0        2   url1
3      0        3   vol1
4      1        0  name2
5      1        1  addr2
6      1        2   url2
7      1        3   vol2
8      2        0  name3
9      2        1  addr3
10     2        2   url3
11     2        3   vol3
```

That will create a data frame that looks like the above (I sorted the columns to more easily visualise what's going on). Then unstack your data.

```
>>> df.set_index(['rows', 'columns']).unstack()
          data                   
columns      0      1     2     3
rows                             
0        name1  addr1  url1  vol1
1        name2  addr2  url2  vol2
2        name3  addr3  url3  vol3
```

After this, collapse columns multi-index `df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(1)` and then rename `df.rename(columns={INT: NAME, INT: NAME, ...}, inplace=True)`. If you have different variable names, adjust as required.

Comment: df['columns'] = df.index % 4 is not giving me an even series meaning 
I am getting something like
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
3
4
5 
which in turn is messing up the output any suggestions/recommendations?
Thanks

Comment: `df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Resetting the index would force the existing index, which it seems is not a simple serial count of the rows (from 0), to become a simple serial count.

Comment: Thanks @ifly6 
Got the required output